# How to prevent iostreams::mapped_file_sink from creating executable txt files

Tags: c++, boost, boost-iostreams

EDIT: code sample is broken, it is missing .is_open(), please DON'T use it. 
I have a rather strange question. I use boost iostreams and they work awesome, but the problem is that files that program creates are executable txt files(I'm on ubuntu,msg is :""lol2.txt" is an executable text file."). 
So is there any way to make it a regular nonexecutable file. I would like to  change the code so that it doesnt create executable, files I know I can change the file after it is created from terminal or Nautilus.
btw this is the code that I'm using:

```
void write_file(const std::string& name,string data)
{
    iostreams::mapped_file_params params;
    params.new_file_size=data.size();
    params.path=name;
    iostreams::mapped_file_sink file(params);
    memcpy(file.data(),&data[0],data.size());
}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal complete sample program that compiles and exhibits the behavior you complain about. See http://sscce.org.

Comment: basically making the function write_file into program causes the same behavior as using it in a "big" program. Just tried it. It,s to long to post because I have a bunch of includes and stuff like that, but I commented out everything except the write_file stuff out of my program and I get the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the file creation mask of your process to create non-executable files by default:

```
umask(getumask() & ~(S_IXUSR | S_IXGRP | S_IXOTH));
```

Comment: Hmm, I was hoping that there is a boost parameter for this, but I googled it and found none, so your solution is probably the best one. Tnx